# Interact with a powershell console programatically with R

Tags: r

I'm writing some script in R that run commands in powershell. I create an Excel object in powershel on which i want to do some actions for multiple files.

(Note i'm aware of libraries like `readxl` but i need to deal with some excel encrypted format that the librares does'nt read)

```
commands <- paste(sep = "\n",  glue::glue('
  $objExcel = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application
  $objExcel.visible = $True'),                          # here create excel instance
  do.call(\(...) paste(sep = "\n", ...), Map(           # here a Map on files to run further commands
    file.path(folder_INFO, info_files) |> 
      gsub(pattern = "/", replacement = "\\\\"),
    file.path(
      folder_INFO, gsub("^Parte_(\\d{6}).xls$", "Consumo_comb_\\1.xls", info_files)) |>
        gsub(pattern = "/", replacement = "\\\\"), 
    f = \(xlsfile, xlsfile2) glue::glue(                
     '$Workbook = $objExcel.Workbooks.Open("{ xlsfile }", $False, $True)
      $Workbook2 = $objExcel.Workbooks.Add()
      $Workbook.Sheets.Item("Consumo Combustibles").Copy($Workbook2.Sheets.Item(1))
      $Workbook2.SaveAs("{ xlsfile2 }")
      $Workbook2.Close($False)
      $Workbook.Close($False)
      '))))
```

and then i do

```
system2("powershell", input = commands)
```

I want however have some interaction with the powershell session, so for example send commands one by one and stop sending further commands when some output is detected.

I tried with `fifo`'s in stdin but they block the program on writing

```
tmp_in <- tempfile()
tmp_out <- tempfile()
con_in <- fifo(tmp_in)
con_out <- fifo(tmp_out)

system2("powershell", stdin = tmp_in, invisible = F)
writeLines("Get-Childitem c:\\", con_in)     # blocks
```

So my question is how can i manage to obtain some sort of interactive session of powershell programatically with R.

Thanks.

Comment: No own experience, but came across {processx} (https://processx.r-lib.org/ ) here: https://www.r-bloggers.com/2021/09/how-to-use-system-commands-in-your-r-script-or-package/

Comment: I didn figure out even how to start but i think processx does the job. Thanks very much!